How to find the interface name
I'm trying to configure something on Windows 10.  It contains yaml that looks like this:
multicast_enabled: true
multicast_address: 239.0.0.1
multicast_port: 3003
multicast_interface: "???"

It's the ??? that I'm having troubles with.  This machine has three enabled NICs with IPs on 10.10.1.0/24, 10.10.4.0/24, and 192.168.1.0/24.  I've heard that if you don't define the interface, the chosen NIC could be arbitary, so I'm trying to figure out what to put in here.  I need it on the NIC that has the 192.168.1.0/24 access.
I've tried a few things to collect data:
> wmic nicconfig where "IPEnabled  = True" get ipaddress
...
[00000013] ... Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (3) I225-LM     ... 13  25  {"10.10.4.2"  , "fe80::b0f6:3fe1:39a9:e344"}  25   ... 30:9C:23:29:9A:89  ...{E8B5E073-D683-4B98-8FDA-B35B3032DEFE}...
[00000014] ... Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (3) I225-LM #2  ... 14  13  {"10.10.1.15" , "fe80::f87a:448e:127d:f12a"}  25   ... 9C:6B:00:25:5E:43  ...{575FF7BE-32AA-4D35-B81B-7195F02C2E82}...
[00000015] ... Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (3) I225-LM #3  ... 15  5   {"192.168.1.1", "fe80::11eb:e2cd:968e:ffc" }  25   ... 9C:6B:00:25:6F:37  ...{14C45F9A-D2D0-446D-8281-8A97AA02DD7B}...

>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 25...30 9c 23 29 9a 89 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (3) I225-LM
 13...9c 6b 00 25 5e 43 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (3) I225-LM #2
  5...9c 6b 00 25 6f 37 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (3) I225-LM #3
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================
...

>netsh int ipv4 show interfaces

Idx     Met         MTU          State                Name
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
  1          75  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
 25          25        1500  connected     Rehost
 13          25        1500  connected     Sim Net
  5          25        1500  connected     Eyetracker

What should I put in multicast_interface?

MAC: 9C:6B:00:25:6F:37
UUID: 14C45F9A-D2D0-446D-8281-8A97AA02DD7B
Device: Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (3) I225-LM #3
Name: Eyetracker
Idx: 5

I'm trying to figure out how multicast works on windows, and I found this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/multicast-programming-sample
   struct ip_mreq_source imr; 
   
   imr.imr_multiaddr.s_addr  = grpaddr;
   imr.imr_sourceaddr.s_addr = srcaddr;
   imr.imr_interface.s_addr  = iaddr;
   return setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP, (char *) &imr, sizeof(imr)); 

In this example interface is selected by an ip_mreq_source object, and the definition of that object says this about imr_interface:

The local IPv4 address of the interface or the interface index on which the multicast group should be joined, dropped, blocked, or unblocked. This value is in network byte order. If this member specifies an IPv4 address of 0.0.0.0, the default IPv4 multicast interface is used.

And I think that's my problem.  If I specify the wrong name for multicast_interface, it'll go to 0.0.0.0 which will select the "default" interface, which is probably not the intended interface.  What could be used to translate an interface name into "192.168.1.0"?
I tried setting multicast_interface: "Eyetracker", but I still didn't see any multi-cast functionality from the program.
I don't know if I need to try multicast_interface: "Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (3) I225-LM #3", or if I should try without the quotes, or maybe use the Idx of the device.

I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding of multicast here, but maybe not. Multicast addresses aren't usually inherently tied to a particular interface, but rather an address that is subscribed to through the IGMP protocol. When it hits 0.0.0.0, that can be interpreted as "any" rather than "default," but it should find a host on the network if all the other devices in the spanning tree are aware of the multicast group. Hopefully this helps, but if not, please elaborate on the diagnosis.
